# Is there a way to set up a rule in Outlook 2010 based on more than one header?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

I'm trying to setup a rule in Outlook 2010 that examines the headers of a message.

The problem is that it seems I can only create a condition for the rule based on whether a message's header contains some text OR some other text.

I need the condition to be `sometext1 AND sometext2`.    Since these two strings are separate I can't use `sometext1 sometext2` since they won't necessarily appear next to each other.  When I add the strings separately it wants to `OR` them together.  It is sort of like I need to be able to add an additional "with specific words in the message header" check box to the conditions.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Outlook doesn't allow anything but `OR`, but I did find a workaround using categories you can try.

[Using AND operators in rules](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/220)

It's not written specifically for message headers, rather for message body, but should work the same since the rule is using a text search.

Comment: That works, cool.  Too bad it is such a pain to setup.  Oh well, maybe in the next version of Office...